# AngularStrap hide popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

The popover can be open via this:

index.html

```
<button id="myid2"> myid2 </button>
<button id="myid3"> myid3 </button>

<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="showpopover('#myid2')">show popover myid2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="showpopover('#myid3')">show popover myid3</a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.showpopover = function(el){
    var myPopover = $popover(angular.element(el), {title: el, content: 'My Content',show:true, placement:'bottom'});
};
```

How can I close the opened popover via script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the popover from outside you cann call `myPopover.hide()`. From inside the popover you can call the `$hide()` function from the popover scope to close the popover.

There's also an option `autoClose` which closes the popover when the user clicks outside of the popover.